# How can I run a Verdaccio instance behind apache2 (ReverseProxy)?

Tags: apache, npm, registry, verdaccio

I have a Debian 12 Server running Apache and Node v20.11.0. The root site (e.g., https://my-website.com/) is reachable and working as expected.

Additionally, I have installed Verdaccio 5.29 on the server using the command `npm install --global verdaccio`. Verdaccio is running as expected with the HTTP address `http://localhost:4873`.

I have been trying to configure a reverse proxy in Apache to use Verdaccio with the root URL and the npm prefix like this: `https://my-website.com/npm`. In order to achieve that, I have followed these instructions:

- [Verdaccio Reverse Proxy Documentation](https://verdaccio.org/docs/reverse-proxy/)
- [Verdaccio Configuration: URL Prefix](https://verdaccio.org/docs/configuration/#url-prefix)

Unfortunately, I cannot make it work. When I introduce `https://my-website.com/npm` in my browser, Verdaccio receives the request and I can see the following Verdaccio logs:

```
info --- plugin successfully loaded: verdaccio-htpasswd
info --- plugin successfully loaded: verdaccio-audit
warn --- http address - http://localhost:4873/ - verdaccio/5.29.0
info <-- 127.0.0.1 requested 'GET /'
http <-- 304, user: null(2001:9e8:460a:6c00:7e44:440e:848f:60c6 via 127.0.0.1), req: 'GET /', bytes: 0/0
http <-- 304, user: null(2001:9e8:460a:6c00:7e44:440e:848f:60c6 via 127.0.0.1), req: 'GET /', bytes: 0/0
info <-- 127.0.0.1 requested 'GET //-/static/runtime.6f77b927373eea0554c8.js'
http <-- 200, user: null(2001:9e8:460a:6c00:7e44:440e:848f:60c6 via 127.0.0.1), req: 'GET //-/static/runtime.6f77b927373eea0554c8.js', bytes: 0/0
http <-- 404, user: null(2001:9e8:460a:6c00:7e44:440e:848f:60c6 via 127.0.0.1), req: 'GET //-/static/runtime.6f77b927373eea0554c8.js', error: File not found
info <-- 127.0.0.1 requested 'GET //-/static/vendors.6f77b927373eea0554c8.js'
http <-- 200, user: null(2001:9e8:460a:6c00:7e44:440e:848f:60c6 via 127.0.0.1), req: 'GET //-/static/vendors.6f77b927373eea0554c8.js', bytes: 0/0
http <-- 404, user: null(2001:9e8:460a:6c00:7e44:440e:848f:60c6 via 127.0.0.1), req: 'GET //-/static/vendors.6f77b927373eea0554c8.js', error: File not found
info <-- 127.0.0.1 requested 'GET //-/static/main.6f77b927373eea0554c8.js'
http <-- 200, user: null(2001:9e8:460a:6c00:7e44:440e:848f:60c6 via 127.0.0.1), req: 'GET //-/static/main.6f77b927373eea0554c8.js', bytes: 0/0
http <-- 404, user: null(2001:9e8:460a:6c00:7e44:440e:848f:60c6 via 127.0.0.1), req: 'GET //-/static/main.6f77b927373eea0554c8.js', error: File not found
```

However, I only get a white page in my browser with the following errors:

[image]

This is the Apache configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName https://my-website.com

        ServerAdmin admin@my-website.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        # LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example, the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        # Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/privkey.pem

        SSLProxyEngine on
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
        ProxyPass /npm http://127.0.0.1:4873/ nocanon
        ProxyPassReverse /npm http://127.0.0.1:4873/
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

In Verdaccio, I have set the environment variable `$VERDACCIO_PUBLIC_URL`. The configuration file looks as follows:

```yaml
storage: /home/topsonic/.local/share/verdaccio/storage
# path to a directory with plugins to include
plugins: ./plugins

# https://verdaccio.org/docs/webui
web:
  title: npm

# https://verdaccio.org/docs/configuration#authentication
auth:
  htpasswd:
    file: ./htpasswd
    # Maximum amount of users allowed to register, defaults to "+inf".
    # You can set this to -1 to disable registration.
    # max_users: 1000
    # Hash algorithm, possible options are: "bcrypt", "md5", "sha1", "crypt".
    # algorithm: bcrypt # by default is crypt, but is recommended use bcrypt for new installations
    # Rounds number for "bcrypt", will be ignored for other algorithms.
    # rounds: 10

# https://verdaccio.org/docs/configuration#uplinks
# a list of other known repositories we can talk to
uplinks:
  npmjs:
    url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

# Learn how to protect your packages
# https://verdaccio.org/docs/protect-your-dependencies/
# https://verdaccio.org/docs/configuration#packages
packages:
  '@*/*':
    # scoped packages
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    unpublish: $authenticated
    proxy: npmjs

  '**':
    # allow all users (including non-authenticated users) to read and
    # publish all packages
    #
    # you can specify usernames/groupnames (depending on your auth plugin)
    # and three keywords: "$all", "$anonymous", "$authenticated"
    access: $all

    # allow all known users to publish/publish packages
    # (anyone can register by default, remember?)
    publish: $authenticated
    unpublish: $authenticated
    # if package is not available locally, proxy requests to 'npmjs' registry
    proxy: npmjs

server:
  keepAliveTimeout: 60
  # Allow `req.ip` to resolve properly when Verdaccio is behind a proxy or load-balancer
  # See: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html
  # trustProxy: '127.0.0.1'

# https://verdaccio.org/docs/configuration#offline-publish
# publish:
#   allow_offline: false

url_prefix: '/npm'

middlewares:
  audit:
    enabled: true

# https://verdaccio.org/docs/logger
# log settings
log: { type: stdout, format: pretty, level: http }
```

Does anybody have an idea where the issue is? Any help will be appreciated.